# Accordion selection not working properly on clicking on one of them using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

In accordion I have two fields one is State 1 and other is State 2. I want to change the border colors of the text boxes. When I will click on the State 1 it should make some text boxes boundary red while others should be gray. If click on State 2 all the textboxes should be gray and the one of them should be red (the logic for getting the selecting the box to be red I am leaving for the time being).

I have written the following code to achieve this. The only problem I have is if I am using if I click on the first option of the code i.e. State 1 the code works fine while if I click on the second option State 2 the code does not work (i.e. the required text box is not red and all other are not gray)

```
  $("div a").live('click', function() {
      if($(this).text()=="State 1"||selected_accord=="State 1")
      {
         $('input').css('border-color', 'gray');
      if(fromi==1)
      { 
        document.getElementById(input_from[0].id).style.borderColor = "red";
        }

    }

       if($(this).text()=="State 2"||selected_accord=="State 2")
      {
         $('input').css('border-color', 'gray');
        if(userkeyi==1)
        {
        document.getElementById(input_userkey[0].id).style.borderColor = "red";
         }
      }
});
```

Comment: Create a demo using jsfiddle.net please

Comment: You're using `getElementById` to get elements you already have?

Comment: Maybe you could display the html as well?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have uploaded the code on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine. Only change I did was remove selected_accord. I was not able to make the boxes red by default so I used this variable. But for the other accord option this variable was not defined. That was the problem with the second option not working.